# NTFS hard drive is read only

Tags: permissions, mount, samba, 22.04, ntfs

I have a NTFS drive attached via SATA cable to my Ubuntu server running version 22.04. It's a Western Digital Red hard drive.

I auto mounted it via fstab:

```
UUID=C0864343244110   /home/media/backupPictures   ntfs  defaults  0   2
```

I tried below:

```
UUID=C0864343244110   /home/media/backupPictures   ntfs  rw  0   2
```

And also tried setting the permission via:

```
sudo chmod +rwx backupPictures
sudo chmod 777 backupPictures
```

And I get this error all the time:

```
chmod: changing permissions of 'backupPictures/': Read-only file system
```

I am using Samba file share and double checked the file share settings for the folder and it's set as below:

```
[Pictures backup]
    comment = Pictures backup
    path = /home/media/backupPictures
    read only = no
    writable = yes
    browsable = yes
```

And clicked restart on smb as well as rebooting the entire system. I cannot copy files into this location but I can see files already stored there.

I then tried to install ntfsfix but that package doesn't exist anymore.

```
 sudo apt-get install ntfsfix
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ntfsfix
```

Is there anything else I can do? Is there a ntfsfix alternative?

Apparently ntfsfix should work via:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdxX # where x is HDD and X is drive number, in my case it was /dev/sda1
```

But this package no longer exists.

This is the Linux Ubuntu Server I am using:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

Comment: Was this drive an internal HDD for a Windows machine before being attached to the server? Alternatively, if this drive has always been an external, was it “safely ejected” from Windows beforehand or was the USB cable simply yanked out? I wonder if the partition is left in an unclean state, which might lead to this sort of behaviour 

Comment: It is not clear how the NTFS "drive" is attached. Is it an external drive attached by an USB cable? Is it an internal drive attached by an internal SATA cable? Is it a NVMe drive plugged into a socket? Please edit your question and add all the clarifications.

Comment: It's attached internally via sata

Comment: You cannot fix NTFS from Linux, you need to use a Windows repair/recovery disk. Best not to use NTFS unless also dual booting with Windows. You also cannot change ownership & permissions on Windows formats. They are not supported without major complications. The defaults are all set during mount. Typical parameters for NTFS: `nodev,windows_names,nosuid,noatime,async,big_writes,timeout=2,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0113,dmask=0022`

Comment: I've researched and found ntfsfix command but the package doesn't exist in Ubuntu server 22.04. Read my original post regarding it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, this worked so far:

```
/partition/identifier   /mount/point    ntfs-3g rw,uid1000,gid1000,umask=0000,fmask=0000    0   0
```

you can also remount it as rw for a quick test:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /partition/identifier /mount/point
```

Comment: This kinda worked. Added u mask and rw and it seemed to work on most of my ntfs drive but there's one that refuses to work

Answer (score 1):

I used this command on Ubuntu 22.04 fixed my NTFS partition read-only:

sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g

after installing, unmount the partition and mount it again
It fixed complete my issue.

Comment: Yeap. That fixed the access to my NTFS partitions. The problem, in addition to the read-only limitation, was that the NTFS required authentication to run the gvfsd- admin daemon. Thank you.